# Can I point the same domain to my app and a wix site by rules?

Tags: dns, velo

I have a WIX site that owns my domain example.com where I built pages for my clients.

Now I have started to invest in my own technology and develop the same product from scratch for my clients but I still cannot migrate WIX clients to my new app. The new app will only serve new customers

I want to find a way for the same domain example.com, through rules, to know whether to go to WIX or to my application hosted in google cloud.

Can you help me with any ideas to achieve this?

Thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean by "through rules", can you give an example?

Comment: @DusanBajic thanks for your answer.

I have my user database in two parts. One part is in WIX databases and the other part is in my new app (for new customers). So the final user go to my domain: example.com/user1 and i need to understand who is user1 and redirect to the right server (Wix or My NodejS APP). But i don't know how and where make this logic

Comment: The list of 'usernames' in wix is static since I will not add new clients there but I have to maintain both sites while I migrate the clients that I have in wix to my new app.

Comment: And i can point the react app to another domain (example.app) but i need that the user enter to the website by example.com/user1 and then i can redirect them to example.app/user1 (My NodeJS APP) or example.com/user1 (my wix site)